# What does 焼く時は translate to?

Tags: food

Is it something like “baked”?

It’s on the wrapper of a caramel pudding kitkat. [image]

Comment: It's part of the full sentence written there. 焼く時は受け皿（トレー・天板）を使用してね！Just to be clear, have you tried interpreting it as part of the whole thing? What's your understanding of the sentence?

Comment: Thank you! I don’t know enough yet to have known that was a sentence and not three separate phrases. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "when cooking", where 焼く is to cook and 時 is time. 焼く時 is literally "at time of cooking."

The entire sentence is

> **焼く時**は受け皿を使用してね 
> Please use a container **when cooking**

Grammatically, the 焼く can be viewed as a relative clause that modifies the noun 時.